# Project Defaults in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have discovered *Property Manager* in Visual Studio 2010. However there are two project properties that I haven't found how to set a default value for. Under *Project Defaults* in the project property pages dialog window, there is *Configuration Type* property whose default value is **Application (.exe)**. I would like the default to be **Dynamic Library (.dll)**. The other property is *Character Set* whose default value is **Use Multi-Byte Character Set** but I would like it to be **Use Unicode Character Set**.

Please note that I have also discovered the file `Microsoft.Cpp.props` but it contains a warning not to edit the file's contents - so I would prefer not to.

Is it possible to set the defaults I desire and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: That was a flaw in VS2010, no access to "General" properties.  Got fixed in later versions.  Maybe VS2012, definitely VS2013.

Comment: So I understand that my options are to either upgrade or edit the `Microsoft.Cpp.props` file, correct?